# Team Foundation Server 2017 Release Management - Publish Build Artifacts to a Fileserver with credentials

Tags: tfs, release-management

It's the first time I'm working withe TFS 2017 Release Management. What I like to do is:
After the Build on the TFS I want to copy/move a .exe file from the TFS Server to another file server like `\\MyFileServer\foo\` with the "Publish Build Artifacts"-Task. But to get access to the file server it needs my credentials. So how do I tell the TFS my credentials to move the file?
I read something about variables, but there is no option to set the variables/credentials to the " Publish Build Artifacts"-Task.

Anyone who had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The build service account needs to have access to the share.

Answer (score 0):

First, in general, the build agent running as network service (service mode), so it uses network service to access that Shared Folder, so you need to make sure the network service account has the enough permission.

You can refer to these ways to grant permission:

1. Right click the shared folder > Properties
2. Select Sharing tab
3. Click Share button
4. Type everyone and click Add button (You can’t add network service account)
5. Change permission level to Read/Write

If the build agent running as interactive mode, you can just add the account that start build agent to the shared folder user list.

Secondly, you can use Server Artifact type instead (Change File Share to Server in Publish Build Artifacts step), after that you can [link artifacts to release](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/understanding-artifacts#link-artifacts-to-a-release-definition) and the artifacts will be download automatically.